# what is the meaning of "Value" class in .proto file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, proto

can someone please explain me the meaning of "Value" in below .proto file?

```proto
message Test {
string id = 1;
string name = 2;
google.protobuf.Value property = 6;}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without an `import` it probably shouldn't work, however: it represents a flexibly typed value; the `Value` "well known type" is essentially a union (`oneof`) of a few common types, with the Java API (from your tags) [described here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Value).

The definition is in [`struct.proto`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto#L63-L79) (hence you'll need `import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";`), or basically:

```proto
message Value {
  // The kind of value.
  oneof kind {
    // Represents a null value.
    NullValue null_value = 1;
    // Represents a double value.
    double number_value = 2;
    // Represents a string value.
    string string_value = 3;
    // Represents a boolean value.
    bool bool_value = 4;
    // Represents a structured value.
    Struct struct_value = 5;
    // Represents a repeated `Value`.
    ListValue list_value = 6;
  }
}
```